# Using unspecialized templated type as template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, dynamic, refactoring

Here is a running example of what I want to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

template <class T> 
struct print
{
    static void function( T thing)
    {
        std::cout << thing << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct printMore
{
    static void function( T thing )
    {
        std::cout << thing << " and more" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct dynamicBase
{
    const char* m_value;

    size_t getType()
    {
        switch( *m_value )
        {
        case '0': //the string is going to be a small script, the type returned is known during execution but not at compile time
            return typeid( int ).hash_code();
        case '1':
            return typeid( float ).hash_code();
        }
        return typeid( const char* ).hash_code();
    }

    template<class T>
    T* tryGetValue()
    {
        if( getType() == typeid( T ).hash_code() )
            return (T*) ( &( m_value[1] ) ); //dumb example, actually I'll evaluate the string as script and return a value based on that
        else
            return nullptr;
    }

    void applyPrint(  )
    {
        if( int* t = tryGetValue<int>() )
            print<int>::function( *t ); //I can cout an int so this line compile
        else if( float* t = tryGetValue<float>() )
            print<float>::function( *t ); //I can cout a float so this one too
        else
            print<const char*>::function( *tryGetValue<const char*>() ); //same
    }
    void applyPrintMore()
    {
        if( int* t = tryGetValue<int>() )
            printMore<int>::function( *t ); 
        else if( float* t = tryGetValue<float>() )
            printMore<float>::function( *t );
        else
            printMore<const char*>::function( *tryGetValue<const char*>() ); //same
    }

    //.... applyprintPretty, applyprintInRed, applyprintInBlue, .....
};

int main()
{
    dynamicBase d;
    d.m_value = "0a\0\0\0";
    d.applyPrint(); //97 == ascii value of 'a'

    __asm {nop}; //for breakpoint purpose
}
```

At first I though I could use a template like this :

```
    template<class myFunctionClass>
    void applyPrint(  )
   {
        if( int* t = tryGetValue<int>() )
            myFunctionClass<int>::function( *t ); 
        else if( float* t = tryGetValue<float>() )
            myFunctionClass<float>::function( *t ); 
        else
            myFunctionClass<const char*>::function( *tryGetValue<const char*>() ); 
    }
```

And then realized my mistake (templated types are not types until you give them template parameters). But is there a way to refactorize this code so I don't have 15 applyStuff functions? (I'm doing it wrong, am I not?)

Comment: `typeid().hash_code` makes my eyes bleed. Eventually, this is destined to be [a feature article on thedailywtf.com](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/You-Cant-Handle-the-True!)

Comment: There is no typeids in the production code. We have our own meta information on types. It's for everyone to understand what this is about without worrying about how we identify types at runtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for *template template parameters*:

```
template<template <typename> class myFunctionClass>
void applyPrint(  )
{
        if( int* t = tryGetValue<int>() )
            myFunctionClass<int>::function( *t ); 
        else if( float* t = tryGetValue<float>() )
            myFunctionClass<float>::function( *t ); 
        else
            myFunctionClass<const char*>::function( *tryGetValue<const char*>() ); 
}
```

You can find a reference [here: "cppreference.com - Template template parameters"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter).

Answer (score 3):

Template template parameters are the answer.

```
template<template <typename> class myFunctionClass>
void apply(  )
{
    if( int* t = tryGetValue<int>() )
        myFunctionClass<int>::function( *t ); 
    else if( float* t = tryGetValue<float>() )
        myFunctionClass<float>::function( *t ); 
    else
        myFunctionClass<const char*>::function( *tryGetValue<const char*>() ); 
}

// ...

apply<print>();
apply<printMore>();
```

For no good reason, they must always say "class" instead of "typename" (though C++ 17 fixes this). The inner set of parameters (here, the bare keyword typename) must be equal in number and kind to the number of parameters that the template uses, though they need not be given names.